# How to send list of values(array) like ids in REST full web service. I need URL syntax and java rest full web service example

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Below rest full web service examples which syntax is correct? How to pass and retrieve the list of ids in restful web service?

```
http://localhost:8080/employee?Ids:{1,2,3} or
http://localhost:8080/employee?Ids=1,2,3 or 
http://localhost:8080/employee?Ids=[1,2,3] or
```

Please help me with syntax or example.

Comment: You can make any of those work. Please show what research you have done already and what code you have tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These should work, have a try:

```
http://localhost:8080/employee?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3
http://localhost:8080/employee?ids=1,2
```